# Algorithm: Dynamic Sum of n Numbers

Tags: algorithm

### Algorithm question

The following array exists `list = [1, 3, 6, 8, 12, 18, 25, 28, 30, 40, 45, 50, 60, 68, 78, 88, 98, 128, 158, 198, 248, 298 , 348, 418, 488, 548, 588, 618, 648, 698, 798, 818, 848, 898, 998, 1048, 1098, 1148, 1198, 1248, 1298, 1398, 1448, 149, 8, 1998 , 2298, 2598, 2998, 3298, 3998, 4498, 4998, 5898, 6498]`, the `target` value is a number, you need to select the sum of `n` numbers from `list` as `target`, `n` The range is `[1,10]`, where items in the list **allow repeated** selection, for example:

#### Example1: Assuming target = 10,

✅ Possible outcomes are as follows:

- Result 1: `10*1 = 10`, => `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`
- Result 2: `1*8 + 2*1 = 10`, => `[8,1,1]`
- Result 3: `1*6 + 3*1 + 1*1 = 10`, => `[6,3,1]`
- Result 4: `3*3 + 1*1 = 10`, => `[3,3,3,1]`
- ...

#### Example2: Assuming target = 20,

✅ Possible outcomes are as follows:

- Result 1: `18*1 + 2*1 = 20`, => `[18,1,1]`
- Result 2: `12*1 + 8*1 = 20`, => `[12,8]`
- ...

❌ Bad Result:

- 20 1s, against the rules: pick up to 10
- [1,2,5], the sum is not right

#### Note

- **Pick a maximum of 10, a minimum of 1, repeatable picks**
- **if no suitable result is found, return `undefined`**

### Solution

#### Solution1- Recursive computation - 10/25/2022

Recursion always solves this kind of problem, maybe there are other better ways, I will keep updating and trying.
[TypeScript Playground - Recursive computation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2gFQKbRgXhgbQFAyEwCMANAUQMzlEwBsNRAHI4cQEysksWHsCsXdj1qUADFwAsE3jEmDZ-GbTrKidEUQDsmwk10wAnAY4n+J40MkH2l2ZWtTiB6wf6PF+rnWfePKu1otQOZfWSZ-ZhDCQ2iSMUi2MTjiYkSSYhT2dI4UyhTJHMkU-hS6HNibWxtSm0quSmqG+tlCuOK48zjyuwBdAG48PFBIWABzVCgAYRAAWwAjBDAAQygEcAgsGAAKRGgALhgAQQAnE+WATwAeMABXBdQTgD5SGChlk4moQ7uHk4BKLBPGAAb1kcEmMBO6EOOF6Wzhg1oENgy0gsPh2ER4KQUAAdBAQCcoNt-kiiPNlsAANbIc7AVC7XGvd6fSavaEQV5orkwMRk2TQqC3E5gKHoQYAX0GIwwlJpdKpqC22xxB2OZ0uN3u80eL1krK+Px1jy4nMOp3O11+uueXB5Fs11pNdtk0A+UAAkmAACaoAAexr+eEBmGBYNoCAAZjtDZCrnyYAAfJMwHl4iFgMZQAAWMGBxH5oNktCFIrA5MIktk0djHy+WEw2CLEdoRE5eIADrcIDntniBzyBW325Ny5WYNXaFGiTsUTAEFt3cTvX7-f0FzAE3t8ZnszmNwgANRHwGtke17Zx2Db3E4BC9QEjNZ3VCDEtEdPd3tM6D3x8TpGMbbB2e65o2zZnh+I7yrS9KMjuLL1pCAC08B3g+HLoNykCvAgw4jpO0FppAXYgJ2pITtW0pDLKsDnFmyrYNsy7fDANqmjA0DkUGtqvNAqCdrxjyhk8siWpceJRicczbCC8CoFmuaHCxUDkTAaGsYCAD0XFQIJMBHiQk6vNsAD6eGiYZ2yLgAVHpgn-AKwwbLA+nQBJFxbAxEzbGQMBKBIJDOTOJxzpCSxrlsYiHr6AZbm86BQJ5GaKfusVrieUG0HRbzIbA2DuclTr3nF-oDLIuWcrccDFVaWxfDMCxLKs6yQL+UBoNASFslABGELlED3N56A1XVknQj6twMts2zLMJJyvMAC1WcshkwMArz8hOl7XjAACETZccNKbikNtUpWBeYFi2xGyiAEIZiAYzbAA5ISszKh9kw5ksYwwAA7opsAAzJWb7K9WHneNFw9V8-VEdWLmQA9qBPS9r2dssEAQK9ApAA)

#### Question

I want to find an optimal solution, speed first.

```js
const list = [
    1,
    3,
    6,
    8,
    12,
    18,
    25,
    28,
    30,
    40,
    45,
    50,
    60,
    68,
    78,
    88,
    98,
    128,
    158,
    198,
    248,
    298,
    348,
    418,
    488,
    548,
    588,
    618,
    648,
    698,
    798,
    818,
    848,
    898,
    998,
    1048,
    1098,
    1148,
    1198,
    1248,
    1298,
    1398,
    1448,
    1498,
    1598,
    1648,
    1998,
    2298,
    2598,
    2998,
    3298,
    3998,
    4498,
    4998,
    5898,
    6498,
];

function getCombinations(
    list: number[],
    target: number
): Array<number> | undefined {
  // TODO...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve this at all. If so please share what you have tried

Comment: Yes, I'm still trying to find a solution worth sharing, I'll keep updating the question.Maybe tomorrow I'll find at least one idea to share.

Answer (score 0):

This is solvable with dynamic programming.  I'll just outline the solution.  I do have other posts where I've actually given working code for problems with similar ideas.  For example [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum/64380474#64380474).

First imagine we have a 2-D data structure with the following information in each `Node`:

```
{
    is_root: true|false,        // True only at the root of the data structure
    current_sum: ...,           // At this node, here is the current sum
    solution_count: ...,        // How many solutions below here
    current_value: ...,         // A value to find more solutions under
    current_value_count: ...,   // How many times this value has been used.
    // First dimension, go back by current_value
    prev_sum_solution: ptr to Node,
    // Second dimension, go back to current sum, previous value
    prev_value_solution: ptr to Node,
}
```

These nodes will hold ONLY information for solutions.  You can report how many there are, or produce the solutions recursively.  If `node.prev_sum_solution` is not `null`, then `node.prev_sum_solution->solution_count` gives how many solutions will have `current_value` next.  And if f `node.prev_value_solution` is not `null`, then `node.prev_value_solution->solution_count` gives how many solutions will have `current_sum` with a previous value next.  This allows you to find any particular solution as well.

Now how do we generate this solution?  Well first we initialize an array of `target+1` pointers to nodes:

```
solution = [null, null, ..., null]
```

And then we replace `solution[0]` with our root node:

```
{
    is_root: true,
    current_sum: 0,
    solution_count: 1,
    current_value: 0,
    current_value_count: 0,
    prev_sum_solution: null,
    prev_value_solution: null,
}
```

(Warning.  I'll use a mix of notations for this pseudo-code. And specifically `.` accesses an object's properties, while `->` accesses properties from a pointer to an object.  You can make the ideas work in any language whether or not it has pointers though.)

And then we go as follows:

```
for value in list:
    // Add solutions that use this value
    for i in range(n): // ie i is in {0, 1, 2, ..., n-1}
        // We iterate down to avoid solutions that use this.
        for (j = list.length-1; (i+1) * value <= j; j--) {
            this_solution = solution[j]
            prev_solution = solution[j-value]
            if prev_solution == null or
               (prev_solution.current_value != value and 0 < i) or
               (prev_solution.current_value_count != i-i):
               continue // can't add value here.
            else:
                if (this_solution == null) {
                    solution[j] = pointer to Node{
                        is_root: false,
                        current_sum: i,
                        solution_count: prev_solution->solution_count,
                        current_value: value,
                        current_value_count: i,
                        prev_sum_solution: prev_solution,
                        prev_value_solution: null,
                    }
                }
                else {
                    solution[i] = pointer to Node{
                        is_root: false,
                        current_sum: j,
                        solution_count: prev_solution->solution_count + this_solution->solution_count,
                        current_value: value,
                        current_value_count: i,
                        prev_sum_solution: prev_solution,
                        prev_value_solution: this_solution,
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And when we are done, if we have no mistakes, `solution[limit]` will hold a pointer to a `Node` that has all the information about all of the possible solutions that exist.